# Dynamic memory allocation C++ through a method

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a template class Stack which needs to have memory allocated on the heap.
The thing is I do not allocate memory on each push deallocate it on each pop, but I know the size that my stack should have before inserting(pushing) elements in it.
So my main look something like :

```
Stack<T> *d = new Stack<T>[n];
for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    d[i].setMem(m);
```

and setMem(m):

```
void setMem(int m) {
    this->stackArray = new Stack<T>[m];
}
```

I am pretty sure that my destructor ~Stack does not free the memory allocated in setMem method.
Any help on how I could free the memory would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want a collection of collections of stacks, why not use a sensible C++ collection like a vector or list?

Comment: Use the destructor? You'll have to have a copy and move constructor, though.

Comment: Can't you just use `std::stack` (and `sttd::vector` if you want a collection of stacks?)

Comment: If you are pretty sure your destructor is not deallocating, then write the code to deallocate. If you think you already wrote the code to deallocate and it's still not working, that would be the single most important piece of code you should have posted.